# Why can't my activity run when one activity jumps to another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, runtime-error

In Android one activity to another activity run but i can't watch anything in second activity on device.

I tried to change run confirmation and run specific activity but at a time same this problem happen.i can't watch anything on device. I just see blank screen on device for few seconds and i come out to application.